# COM DLL - using Mono instead of MS .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, com, dll

I have a DLL written in C# which is acessed by a native EXE (written in Delphi) via COM. Now I was asked to make it work with Mono (on Windows, not Linux) instead of Microsoft .NET Framework.

Is it possible to be done? If it is, how can I do it?

Comment: is the C# dll acting as a COM Callable Wrapper?

Comment: If it isn't a CCW, how do you access it in the Native EXE via COM?

Comment: This solidly fits the "why on Earth would you do that" category.

Comment: Yes, it is a CCW, I guess... maybe I misundestood the concept.

Comment: @Doug - yea, it's probably a CCW. The idea is to just provide a COM-interface can be used by native components yet forward the calls on the interface onto the .Net implementation. Although the project may be possible, I'm with @nobugz on this one - why on earth? You're likely to burn a _lot_ of time getting nowhere. A quick test with SharpDevelop, as I mention below, should give you some idea of how much you're in for.

Comment: @codekaizen - When they asked, I thought 'Why on earth' too. But if it could be easily done, why not? Seems like even if it could be done, it's is not quite easily.

Comment: @Doug - agreed, it seems like it won't be easy. However, I'd recommend spending just an hour trying to get your existing code to build in SharpDevelop, since then you'd have hard evidence of the possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, yes.

Mono has had COM-callable wrappers for a while. Check: http://www.mono-project.com/COM_Interop.

Probably the easiest thing to do is to download [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) and try to compile your existing code for Mono.